# DataGridView - Make Enter button go to next Column instead of next Row

Tags: c#, datagridview

In `DataGridView`, I set the Enter button to go to the next column like the Tab key.  But if anyone edits the cell, it goes to the next row instead. How to resolve this?

Here's my code:

```
int col = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
int row = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

if(col<dataGridView1.ColumnCount-1)
{
    col++;
}
else
{
    col = 0;
    row++;
}

if(row==dataGridView2.RowCount)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

dataGridView2.CurrentCell=dataGridView2[col,row];
//e.Handled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky because the `DataGridView` control automatically handles the Enter key to go to the next row instead of the next column.  Also, there isn't any property to change this directly.

However, there is a workaround you can use to manually change to the next column whenever a user edits a cell and presses Enter.

One way you can do this is to handle the `CellEndEdit` and `SelectionChanged` events on the `DataGridView` control.  In the `CellEndEdit` event, you can set a custom flag that a cell has just been edited.  And then in the `SelectionChanged` event, you can detect this flag and change the current cell to the next column instead of the next row.

Here's a working example of how you can do this:

```
bool hasCellBeenEdited = false;

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Set flag that cell has been edited
    hasCellBeenEdited = true;
}

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If edit flag is set and it's not already the last column, move to the next column
    if (hasCellBeenEdited && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
    {
        int desiredColumn = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1;
        int desiredRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex - 1;

        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[desiredColumn, desiredRow];
        hasCellBeenEdited = false;
    }

    // If edit flag is set and it is the last column, go to the first column of the next row
    else if (hasCellBeenEdited && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1)
    {
        int desiredColumn = 0;
        int desiredRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[desiredColumn, desiredRow];
        hasCellBeenEdited = false;
    }
}
```